# Auto deduction for templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I had a question yesterday in stackoverflow on achieving specific conversions between different template types.

This is the class that was almost proposed. I say almost because I changed small parts of it in hope of simplifying it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
// Helper class

template<bool from, bool to> 
struct ok_to_copy_foos : std::false_type {};

// Define all valid conversions as specializations:

template<>
struct ok_to_copy_foos<false, false> : std::true_type {};

template<>
struct ok_to_copy_foos<true, false> : std::true_type {};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<bool Owner>
class Foo {

static constexpr bool owner_ = Owner;

public:

    Foo() {}

    Foo(const Foo &o)
    {
        static_assert(ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::value, "can only copy from Foo<true> to Foo<false>");
    }

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo) 
    {
        static_assert(ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::value, "can only assign from Foo<true> to Foo<false>");
        return *this;
    }

    template<bool U>
    Foo(const Foo<U> &)
    {
        static_assert(ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::value, "can only copy from Foo<true> to Foo<false>");
    }

    template<bool U>
    Foo &operator=(const Foo<U> &)
    {
        static_assert(ok_to_copy_foos<Owner, Owner>::value, "can only assign from Foo<true> to Foo<false>");
        return *this;
    }

    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << owner_ << " \n";
    }
};
```

In this class the intent is that you can copy or assign but the result should always be a `Foo<false>` while everything else is prohibited. Essentially that means that you cannot copy or assign from `Foo<true>` to Foo`. I am not sure if there is any better way to achieve that but this is what I got at the moment.

However, there is something that will not work as I would like and I wanted some help in achieving that.

```
Foo<true> t;
auto f = t;
```

This will lead in compiler error so the question is can the compiler figure out that auto should actually be `Foo<false>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no. C++ simply does not work this way.

`auto` means: the object being declared is the same type as the expression that initializes it. If this results in a compilation error, the compiler isn't going to try every class it knows about, as an alternative, to see if maybe there's an available conversion that can be used to initialize it from the expression.

Comment: I was kinda expecting that. I guess it is not similar to overload resolution where the compiler will check if a conversion is possible.

Comment: @xerion you could make a function `x` so that `auto f = x(t);` deduces `f` to `Foo<false>`

Answer (score 0):

As @SamVarshavchik writes, `auto` won't do that for you. But I'd like to opine about how you might want to approach this differently:

I feel you're overusing templates here. Essentially, your Owner template argument is *instance-specific data*. Barring other fundamental considerations, it should be a data member of the Foo class. When that's the case, you will be able to easily have assignment operator force the assignee have owner be false. Now, it's true that this won't prevent you from being able to call methods which should not work - so you would throw runtime exceptions rather than compile-time asserts - but if that's of critical importance you can achieve the same effect with subclassing.

Also, it may well be worthwhile to simply have some sort of a proxy or facade class for your `Foo`, or perhaps just an iterator into it, which do not even have the interface for making copies.

With one or both of the above suggestions, you would not even need/want the trait class, since the class definitions and names would make it immediately obvious to both the compiler and the programmer reading the code what can be copied into what.

Comment: This is what I had at the moment, subclassed and the base class assignment operator or copy ctor was always setting the owner to false. Even if in the subclass I delete the functions (only 1 actually) that should not be accessible that does not stop someone from actually calling them from the base class. Sure I could throw an exception but if it is something that can be handled one step earlier, then why not. The compiler can then say pretty much that this is wrong and not just wait for an exception.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that kind of subclassing! I mean for the base class to _not_ have the method you want to avoid - that way you can control who gets to make that call.